# Facebook messenger bot (webhook)

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots

I am trying to integrate facebook bot for my business page and followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/setup)

Copied js code given to setup webhook and created a .js file... but when i tried to verify and save the message it showed was "The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value = '1227072936', received='﻿ app.get('/webho...'".

I am .net developer and have no idea of javascript coding.

Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong?

Comment: _“Copied js code given to setup webhook and created a .js file”_ – where, run via what? (You do realize this is a Node,js example? If you’re a .net developer, then why are you not implementing it _in_ .net?)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code while verify web hook in java

i just create a serlvet with dopost method and then git the request parameters like below .. sure you have something like that in .net

```
        String token = req.getParameter("hub.verify_token");
        if (token != null && !token.equals("")) {
            resp.setContentType("text/html");

            if (token.equals("{verified_token}")) {
                String challenge = req.getParameter("hub.challenge");
                System.out.println("I am WebHock Verification -------->  ");

            }
        }
```

`{verified_token}` is the token i added while verify my webhook url

the webhook url in the image below replaced by my serlvet URL :
[image]
I hope that help you

Comment: you can find it there on my git  :https://github.com/gamal-ahmed/FacebookMessanger_WatsonDialog_VirtualAgent/blob/master/src/main/java/messanger/virtualagent/bot/serlvet/MessangerBot.java

Comment: the full project commited , check the root directory https://github.com/gamal-ahmed/FacebookMessanger_WatsonDialog_VirtualAgent